# How to replace blank space when summing a CSV column

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to build a python script where the script will sum a
column of a large csv file and give me the output. I was able to sum
the columns with the script below:

```
port csv with open("o77069894.out","r+",encoding='utf8') as fin:
headerline = fin.readline()

amount = 0
debit = 0
value = 0
for row in csv.reader(fin,delimiter=","):

    value = float(row[17]) if value else 0.0
    debit+=value
print (debit)
```

But i ran in to an error when i was testing it with csv column with numbers like '12.4 blank space' (the field has blank spaces). So i tried to use: value =row[17].strip() inside the for loop but a error was thrown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sum_csv1_v3_modified.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       for row in csv.reader(fin,delimiter="|"):   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position
>   3213: inval id start byte

I wont be able show the real data as it is confidential but i think as the code was working for other csv files the issue may be due to the blanks. Even if it is a file issue i would like to know how to deal with such fields.
Also i would like to know how can i edit my code to replace ',' or '$' in the numbers. Thanks.

Comment: A [mcve] would help. In this case, some sample data demonstrating your problem is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like '12.4 blank space' is a string. Try str.replace().

```
a = '12.4 blank space'
a = a.replace(' blank space','')
float(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, as there can be some non-ascii character present

```
row[17].encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: You know how i can replace commas in between the numbers ? for example : 12,000.93

Comment: `float(a.replace(',',''))`